# System level key simulation in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am working on a Mac App for OSX 10.10(in swift). There is one feature which has mini virtual keyboard and requires extensive keyboard key press simulation
(Any event would generate tens of key press simulation in sequence).

At present I am using this method from CGEvent

```
CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source: CGEventSource!, virtualKey: CGKeyCode, keyDown: Bool)
```

But it is very slow. (I can literally see the simulation happening one by one)

---

I am specifically looking forward, to make this work using  low level system calls, for better results in context of time.

Can any one recommend some resources for learning/knowing how this could be done. Or is there any open source library ?

---

Following is my code

```
class func postKey(key : Int , flags : CGEventFlags!) {
    let source = CGEventSourceCreate(CGEventSourceStateID(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState)).takeRetainedValue()

    let downKey = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, UInt16(key), true).takeRetainedValue()
    let upKey = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, UInt16(key), false).takeRetainedValue()

    if flags != nil {
        CGEventSetFlags(downKey, flags);
    }

    let loc = CGEventTapLocation(kCGHIDEventTap)
    CGEventPost(loc, downKey)
    CGEventPost(loc, upKey)
}
```

And invoke it in sequence as following example

```
self.postKey(kVK_ANSI_A, flags: CGEventFlags(kCGEventFlagMaskCommand))
self.postKey(kVK_ANSI_C, flags: CGEventFlags(kCGEventFlagMaskCommand))
self.postKey(kVK_ANSI_V, flags: CGEventFlags(kCGEventFlagMaskCommand))
```

Note: App is not sandboxed.

Comment: "But it is very slow" Could this be a threading problem? Show the actual code and the context in which you are using it...